Keycloak persistent session not working with custom recaptcha login flow
I have a custom login with recaptcha flow on Keycloak, and I have replaced the usual browser flow in the Keycloak admin dashboard with this one. Here's the code for the custom class I'm using
package org.keycloak.authentication.authenticator.recaptcha;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowContext;
import org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowError;
import org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException;
import org.keycloak.authentication.Authenticator;
import org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm;
import org.keycloak.connections.httpclient.HttpClientProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.Details;
import org.keycloak.events.Errors;
import org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProvider;
import org.keycloak.models.AuthenticatorConfigModel;
import org.keycloak.models.utils.FormMessage;
import org.keycloak.protocol.LoginProtocol.Error;
import org.keycloak.services.ServicesLogger;
import org.keycloak.services.messages.Messages;
import org.keycloak.services.validation.Validation;
import org.keycloak.util.JsonSerialization;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm extends UsernamePasswordForm implements Authenticator{
    public static final String G_RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE = "g-recaptcha-response";
    public static final String SITE_KEY = "site.key";
    public static final String SITE_SECRET = "secret";
    public static final String USE_RECAPTCHA_NET = "useRecaptchaNet";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm.class);

    private String siteKey;

    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        context.getEvent().detail(Details.AUTH_METHOD, "auth_method");
        displayRecaptcha(context);
        super.authenticate(context);
    }

    private void displayRecaptcha(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        AuthenticatorConfigModel captchaConfig = context.getAuthenticatorConfig();
        LoginFormsProvider form = context.form();
        String userLanguageTag = context.getSession().getContext().resolveLocale(context.getUser()).toLanguageTag();

        if (captchaConfig == null || captchaConfig.getConfig() == null
                || captchaConfig.getConfig().get(SITE_KEY) == null
                || captchaConfig.getConfig().get(SITE_SECRET) == null) {
            form.addError(new FormMessage(null, Messages.RECAPTCHA_NOT_CONFIGURED));
            return;
        }

        String siteKey = captchaConfig.getConfig().get(SITE_KEY);
        form.setAttribute("recaptchaRequired", true);
        form.setAttribute("recaptchaSiteKey", siteKey);
        form.addScript("https://www." + getRecaptchaDomain(captchaConfig) + "/recaptcha/api.js?hl=" + userLanguageTag);
  } 


    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
        List<FormMessage> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean success = false;
        context.getEvent().detail(Details.AUTH_METHOD, "auth_method");
        String captcha = formData.getFirst(G_RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE);
        if (!Validation.isBlank(captcha)) {
            AuthenticatorConfigModel captchaConfig = context.getAuthenticatorConfig();
            String secret = captchaConfig.getConfig().get(SITE_SECRET);
            success = validateRecaptcha(context, success, captcha, secret);
        }
        displayRecaptcha(context);
        if (success) {
            super.action(context);
        } else {
            errors.add(new FormMessage(null, Messages.RECAPTCHA_FAILED));
            formData.remove(G_RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE);
            context.getEvent().error(Messages.RECAPTCHA_FAILED);
            Response challengeResponse = context.form()
                .setError(Messages.RECAPTCHA_FAILED)
                .createLoginUsernamePassword();
            context.forceChallenge(challengeResponse);
            return;
        }
    }

    private String getRecaptchaDomain(AuthenticatorConfigModel config) {
        Boolean useRecaptcha = Optional.ofNullable(config)
                .map(configModel -> configModel.getConfig())
                .map(cfg -> Boolean.valueOf(cfg.get(USE_RECAPTCHA_NET)))
                .orElse(false);
        if (useRecaptcha) {
            return "recaptcha.net";
        }

        return "google.com";
    }
    protected boolean validateRecaptcha(AuthenticationFlowContext context, boolean success, String captcha, String secret) {
        logger.info("validateRecaptcha(AuthenticationFlowContext, boolean, String, String) start");

        HttpClient httpClient = context.getSession().getProvider(HttpClientProvider.class).getHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www." + getRecaptchaDomain(context.getAuthenticatorConfig()) + "/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        List<NameValuePair> formparams = new LinkedList<>();
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secret", secret));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response", captcha));
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
            post.setEntity(form);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
            try {
                Map json = JsonSerialization.readValue(content, Map.class);
                Object val = json.get("success");
                success = Boolean.TRUE.equals(val);
            } finally {
                content.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ServicesLogger.LOGGER.recaptchaFailed(e);
        }
        return success;
    }
}

For some reason, keycloak's persistent session using rememberMe is not working with this flow. I'm thinking the the rememberMe value is not being passed correctly but can't really pinpoint where the issue is since I have no prior experience with JAVA and Keycloak is a really thick application to wrap your head around. Any help or points would be appreciated.
